# Troubles Updating Values of Selected Features with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, fields-attributes

I'm trying to  modify the values of some selected features. I have written this small script, but nothing happens when I run it. Is there something that I've missed? Here is my code.

```
lyr = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
features = lyr.selectedFeatures()

lyr.startEditing()
lyr.updateFields()
for f in features:
    fid= f.id()
    lyr.changeAttributeValue(fid,12,"0")
    lyr.updateFeature(f)

print "elemento alterado"

lyr.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `lyr.updateFeature(f)` line that is inside your for loop. You don't need it and, according to [the docs](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a125a2f00703d7e3c07b2c26801799ee1), it's also inefficient.

If that doesn't work, make sure the 13th field is of type `String`.

Comment: My guess about what's happening: `lyr.changeAttributeValue(fid,12,"0")` updates the value, but the object in `f` remains unchanged. So `lyr.updateFeature(f)` reverts it *back to the original value*. Is that right?

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand how updateFeature does its job. I just identified a method that works modifying feature attributes (according to the API, there are several ways) and use it every time. I haven't needed updateFeature at all. Perhaps a QGIS core dev could help us here.