# Improve performance when iterating features in QGIS and using "for" loops

Tags: pyqgis, iterator, loop, list, qgis-2.14

I am trying to modify attributes of features in QGIS comparing attributes with list'elements.
First I define new attributes that need to be completed:

```
layer_intersected.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("ID_acc",QVariant.Int,
    QgsField("Nb_acc", QVariant.Int)])
layer_intersected.updateFields()
```

Then, I iterate over my features:

```
layer_intersected.startEditing()
for feature in layer_intersected.getFeatures():
```

I have two lists containing elements.
Now, I want to test if the first attribute ("NOMBRE") is in one of the extracts of "list1" (the list is divided into a certain number of elements, each part of elements is  an 'extract' of list) and if the second attribute ("nombre_2") is also in the same extract of "list2":

```
for i in xrange(0, len(list1), len(list_streets_network)):
    l_streets_t1 = list1[i:i+len(list_streets_network)]
    set_l_streets_t1 = set(list1[i:i+len(list_streets_network)])
    set_l_streets_t2 = set(list2[i:i+len(list_streets_network)])
    l_id = list_id_acc[i:i+len(list_streets_network)]
    l_acc = list_nb_acc[i:i+len(list_streets_network)]
    if feature["NOMBRE"] in set_l_streets_t1 and feature["nombre_2"] in set_l_streets_t2:
```

Then, if it is the case, I complete the attributes created

```
         index1 = l_streets_t1.index(feature["NOMBRE"])
         feature["ID_acc"] = l_id[index1]
         feature["Nb_acc"] = l_acc[index1]
         layer_intersected.updateFeature(feature)
```

Finally:

```
layer_intersected.commitChanges() 
return layer_intersected
```

My problem is the speed of this code. I have to do this for thousands of features, and it takes days to calculate... I am sure there is a faster solution, but I do not know how to improve it...

I had a look on Numpy doc, but did not find the best solution...
If someone has an idea, please help me ! :).

Here is the full code of the function:

```
> def create_id_for_right_matches(layer_intersected, list1, list2, list_id_acc, list_nb_acc, list_streets_network): 
    layer_intersected.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("ID_acc", QVariant.Int), QgsField("Nb_acc", QVariant.Int)])
    layer_intersected.updateFields()
    layer_intersected.startEditing()
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry).setSubsetOfAttributes(['NOMBRE', 'nombre_2'], layer_intersected.fields())
        for feature in layer_intersected.getFeatures(request):
            for i in xrange(0, len(list1), len(list_streets_network)):
                l_streets_t1 = list1[i:i+len(list_streets_network)]
                set_l_streets_t1 = set(list1[i:i+len(list_streets_network)]) 
                set_l_streets_t2 = set(list2[i:i+len(list_streets_network)]) 
                l_id = list_id_acc[i:i+len(list_streets_network)]
                l_acc = list_nb_acc[i:i+len(list_streets_network)]
                if feature["NOMBRE"] in set_l_streets_t1 and feature["nombre_2"] in set_l_streets_t2:
                    index1 = l_streets_t1.index(feature["NOMBRE"])
                    feature["ID_acc"] = l_id[index1]
                    feature["Nb_acc"] = l_acc[index1]
                    layer_intersected.updateFeature(feature)
    layer_intersected.commitChanges()
    return layer_intersected
```

Comment: 1) Remove the `layer_intersected.updateFeature(feature)` line. [You don't need it and it's inefficient](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175947/troubles-updating-values-of-selected-features-with-pyqgis/175950#175950). 2) Here you can find tips to optimize your `getFeatures()` call: http://nyalldawson.net/2016/10/speeding-up-your-pyqgis-scripts/

Comment: @GermánCarrillo It does not work when I remove the "updatefeature" line...

Comment: Try switching to this way of changing feature attributes `layer.changeAttributeValue(fid, fieldIndex, newValue)` (as indicated in the post I mentioned) instead of `feature["ID_acc"] = l_id[index1]` because, I repeat, `updateFeature(feature)` is inefficient.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo I tested it, and it takes longer compare to "updateFeature" way...

Comment: @GermánCarrillo Otherwise, I added "Trap3" with "request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry).setSubsetOfAttributes(['value'], vector_layer.fields() )". It improves the code 1.27% better (97,45 sec instead of 98,70). Others traps are not available for my purpose because I really need to iterate over all features...

Comment: Post your full code. Broken out like that is hard to read.

Comment: @NathanW You can see the full code on my answer :).

Comment: @GermánCarrillo Do you have other tips for me or not ?

Comment: Does someone has an idea to improve this code ?

Answer (score 1):

I improved my code by inversing "for" loops, that gains time, but not enough...

Now my code looks like :

> 

```
    layer_intersected.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("ID_acc", QVariant.Int), QgsField("Nb_acc", QVariant.Int)])
    layer_intersected.updateFields()
    layer_intersected.startEditing()
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry).setSubsetOfAttributes(['NOMBRE', 'nombre_2'], layer_intersected.fields())
    for i in xrange(0, len(list1), len(list_streets_network)):
        l_streets_t1 = list1[i:i+len(list_streets_network)]
        set_l_streets_t1 = set(list1[i:i+len(list_streets_network)])
        set_l_streets_t2 = set(list2[i:i+len(list_streets_network)])
        l_id = list_id_acc[i:i+len(list_streets_network)]
        l_acc = list_nb_acc[i:i+len(list_streets_network)]
        for feature in layer_intersected.getFeatures(request):
            if feature["NOMBRE"] in set_l_streets_t1 and feature["nombre_2"] in set_l_streets_t2:
                index1 = l_streets_t1.index(feature["NOMBRE"])
                feature["ID_acc"] = l_id[index1]
                feature["Nb_acc"] = l_acc[index1]
                layer_intersected.updateFeature(feature)
```

If someone has another idea, I would be pleased to hear from him...

Thanks